# redirect to folder htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am redesigning my site and for that I put all the old content into a temp folder. However I would still like to access it using the main URL and I don't want the user to have any idea that they were redirected. I tried a few variations of the code bellow that I found on Google but nothing seems to work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bm-temp/$1
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your rewriterule with

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/bm-temp/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bm-temp/$1 [L,QSA]
```